# using isql query the db2 database ,the result of the column value not correct

Tags: sql, linux, db2, isql

first i use the dbvisulizer to query the db2 database ,using the follow sql ,the correct result as blow:

[image]

next i use the isql in liux ,using the same sql,however the result of the sql not same as  firt reulst i did.

[image]

can you help me?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to give an answer.  Specifically you have not proved that DbVisualizer  and unixODBC are both pointing at the same database.  Additionally, your question should not use graphics, instead you should use plain text -- because plain text is searchable and easier for many people to read.

Comment: my question is when i use the isql to query the db2 database,the real column of value is blank but ,the query result   the column shows  it's have value.

Comment: I understood your question, but clearly you did not understand my comment. Think!

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.